# VS C# List Available (Not in Use) Serial Ports

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am writing my first ever program in C# using Visual Studio, I have a function that populates a dropdown with 'available' COM ports. How do I check if one of these 'available' ports is not open outside of my program?

```
    foreach (string portName in System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames())
    {
        serialPort1.PortName = portName;
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen == false) // Only list if it is not in use - does not work - .IsOpen is only valid from within this app
        {
            CommsBox.Items.Add(portName);
        }
    }
```

I hoped to do this but it does not work.

Comment: Such code can never work reliably on a multi-tasking operating system.  You cannot find out until you call Open().  At which point you get a crystal-clear exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initialize `serialPort1`?

You should create a new instance of `SerialPort`, and open it to know if it's free like this:

```
foreach (string portName in System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames())
    {
        try{
            SerialPort serialPort1 = new SerialPort();
            serialPort1.PortName = portName;
            serialPort1.Open();
            CommsBox.Items.Add(portName); //If you can open it it's because it was free, so we can add it to available
            serialPort1.Close(); //Should close it again
            }
        catch (Exception ex){
            //manage the exception...
        }
    }
```

[More information about 'SerialPort' class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx)

**EDIT:**

The best solution is follow @Baddack comment:

"Hans Passant said it the best: "Such code can never work reliably on a multi-tasking operating system. You cannot find out until you call Open(). At which point you get a crystal-clear exception.". You should really just populate the combobox with all the COM ports and let the user decide. If the COM port is in use, then a exception is thrown and you can handle that however you please."

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? Makes sense but I hoped that there is a better way than actually trying to open every serial port to see if they are in use elsewhere.

Comment: Well, actually this is the only method I know to test if you can use a SerialPort. I'll be alert if someone gives an other optimal solution :)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but its not really a good idea to go through the whole list of available serial ports and open and close them all.  It might be ok if you are doing some development on a machine where you know all the ports and what is on the other end of each one, but for use on someone elses PC where you don't know the environment, this is generally bad practice.

Comment: Any ideas @Baddack??

Comment: Hans Passant said it the best: "Such code can never work reliably on a multi-tasking operating system. You cannot find out until you call Open(). At which point you get a crystal-clear exception.".  You should really just populate the combobox with all the COM ports and let the user decide.  If the COM port is in use, then a exception is thrown and you can handle that however you please.

Comment: Thank you for the comments! I will let the user decide.