# Remove ghost com port programmatically C#

Tags: c#, windows, registry, com-port

There is a way to Removes ghost devices from your system in C#? I have try with "ManagementObjectSearcher" with "From Win32_Device" or "Win32_PnPEntity" but with not success. Thanks

[image: Element to remove]

With powerShell there is this command:

```
Get-PnpDevice -class "Ports" -status unknown
```

I have to execute it in c# and I have to remove the "unknown" devices

Comment: I have try to remove/reset the registry entry at path "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM",  "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\COM Name Arbiter" but i I go to "Device Manager" if i show the hidden device is till present.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop between every port at the startup and try to open it, so you can identify which one exist and it's available. [Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38694244/vs-c-sharp-list-available-not-in-use-serial-ports)